# Exclude most recent post

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm looking to make the front page of my Jekyll site have the most recent post followed by links to the 3 or so other most recent posts. I would have thought that this would do so:

```
<!-- first post -->

{% for post in site.posts[1..3] %}
    <!-- link to posts -->
{% endfor %}
```

How can I get the second through fourth posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:3 offset:1 %}
    <!-- link to posts -->
{% endfor %}
```